# Login error using loginmanager

Tags: android, facebook

When i try login to facebook apps i got this error :

```
Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. please try again later
```

Here is my code :

```
 btnLoginFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFacebook);
    btnLoginFacebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("permissionNeeds"));
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "go to facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

it always return onError after i click okay on the facebook apps. I already add onActivityResult method below this method. Here is my onActivityResult method :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    Profile.getCurrentProfile();
}
```

Anyone got this problem too ?

Comment: can you use other features ? I had the same problem but it was about hash key

Comment: @firativerson yeah it turned out the hash key was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem it turned out the hash key was wrong. You need to change the hash key to the correct one

Answer (score 0):

check your fb sdk version. you are encountering this problem because you are compiling an old version of facebook sdk in your project. you are using Graph API v2.0 which is no longer available as of August 7, 2016.